# JS for loop only checks first radio button

Tags: javascript, for-loop

why my loop only checks first radio button, and if I select 2nd or third it doesn't work?

```
function checkit(){
        for(var i=0;i<document.forms[0].test.length;i++){
            if(document.forms[0].test[i].checked === true){
                alert('OK');
                break;
            }else { alert('hmz'); break; }
        }
    }

<form onsubmit="checkit();">
    First: <input type="radio" name="test"><br>
    Second: <input type="radio" name="test"><br>
    Third: <input type="radio" name="test"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Lets try it!">
</form>
```

Thank your for reply's. As noted, I have to take off break. But than another problem occurs, every time I press submit if any box is selected it gives me 3 alert box's. How to stop it?

Comment: You're always calling `break` which leaves the loop

Comment: Because you're using a `break` in the first if condition. Remove it and it should work.

Comment: I wonder what OP thinks `break` actually means

Comment: Probably he thinks it's used as in Pascal's case statements, where you need to break or the next case will also be executed! :)

Comment: I thought you need to leave loop once you find selected radio, otherwise, once i take off break, i get alert 3boxs.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) which leaves the loop.

```
function checkit() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].test.length; i++) {
        if (document.forms[0].test[i].checked === true) {
            alert('OK');
        } else {
            alert('hmz');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but then I get 3 alert box's. How to stop looping once it found that box is selected?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question. But I advise you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it would be helpful in your case. To get the radio button checked with jQuery: `$('form:radio:checked').val()`. Without loop.

Comment: I need display alert box OK, if any of those box's are selected. Loop works, but it prompts 3alert boxs, every time I press submit button. And with break I could have prevented it.